# How to implement configFileProvider into shared Libraries?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to have the use of configFileProvider inside a Jenkins Shared Libraries class. In a structure similar to the following:

```
.
├── src
│   └── org
│       └── sharedLibraries
│           └── tools
│               └── ConfigFileOperator.groovy <--- Implementation of configFileProvider
└── vars
    └── executer.groovy
```

I have tried to develop it in the following way.

executer.groovy

```
import org.sharedLibraries.tools.ConfigFileOperator

def call(body) {

    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    cfo = new ConfigFileOperator(steps)
    cfo.loadFileConfig(config.FILE_ID, circuit, enviroment)
}
```

ConfigFileOperator.groovy

```
package org.sharedLibraries.tools

import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL
import net.sf.json.JSONObject

class ConfigFileOperator implements Serializable {

    def JSONObject configFileJson
    def boolean isArray
    def DSL steps

    ConfigFileOperator (DSL steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }

    def loadFileConfig (String fileID, String circuit, String enviroment) {
        def props
        steps.configFileProvider([steps.configFile(fileId: fileID, variable: 'configJson')]) {
            props = steps.readJSON file: configJson
            jl.echoInfo('Config load.')
        }
        this.configFileJson = props.get(circuit).get(enviroment)
    }
}
```

But the development fails indicating that Jenkins does not get the "configJson" variable and immediately after that the build fails.

Jenkins error stack:

```
14:46:29  hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: configJson for class: org.sharedLibraries.tools.ConfigFileOperator
14:46:29    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
14:46:29    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
14:46:29    at org.sharedLibraries.tools.ConfigFileOperator.loadFileConfig(ConfigFileOperator.groovy:21)
14:46:29    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
14:46:29    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor892.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:46:29    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:46:29    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
14:46:29    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
14:46:29    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
14:46:29    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
14:46:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
14:46:29    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
14:46:29    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
14:46:29    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
14:46:29    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
14:46:29    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
14:46:29    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
14:46:29    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
14:46:29    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
14:46:29    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do the implementation without having to put the ConfigFileOperator in the jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've fixed this already but just in case someone else benefits

This might do the trick

```
props = steps.readJSON file: '${steps.configJson}'
```

Your question got me to something similar to the following:

```
package my.test.package

class Config {

  public static final def getSettings(Script script) {
    script.configFileProvider([script.configFile(fileId: '<YOUR CONFIG FILE ID HERE>', variable: 'settings')]) {
      def someSettings=script.readJSON file: "${script.settings}"
      return someSettings
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
@Library('my-shared-library')
import my.test.package.Config

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test it') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def config=Config.getSettings(this)
                    print(config)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```